# How to bind multiple sequential events in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to bind multiple sequential events using jquery. I want to do the following:

> Click on `div1` - aka mousedown event -
>   now, IF you start moving the mouse while you are STILL pressing down on the mouse, THEN do some function.

What's the smoothest way of doing this? Just to put an `if` inside of a `.on()` call, or is there something simpler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to achieve this.

```
var $div = $("div");

var mousemove = function() { ... };

$div.on({
  mousedown: function() {
    $div.on("mousemove", mousemove);
  },
  mouseup: function() {
    $div.off("mousemove", mousemove);
  }
});​
```

Notice that `.on()` and `.off()` are the recommended methods to bind and unbind events respectively.

[You can check a live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/XjraY/)

---

### UPDATE

Alternatively, you can bind the `mouseup` event to the `document`. This way you can detect the release of the mouse even if it doesn't occur while hovering your element.

```
var $document = $(document);
var $div = $("div");

var mousemove = function() { ... };

$div.mousedown(function() {
  $div.on("mousemove", mousemove);
})

$document.mouseup(function() {
  $div.off("mousemove", mousemove);
});​
```

---

Also, a shorthand function for it. Let's call it `.drag()`.

```
$.fn.drag = function(fn) {
  var $document = $(document);
  return $(this).each(function() {
    var self = this;
    var $this = $(this);
    var mousemove = function() {
      fn.dragging && fn.dragging.call($this);
    };
    $this.mousedown(function() {
      fn.start && fn.start.call($this);
      fn.dragging && $this.on("mousemove", mousemove);
    });
    $document.mouseup(function() {
      fn.dragging && $this.off("mousemove", mousemove);
      fn.stop && fn.stop.call(self);
    });
  });
};
```

```
$("div").drag({
  start: function() { ... },
  dragging: function() { ... },
  stop: function() { ... }
});​
```

[You can see it live here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPZqQ/)

Comment: +1 This is nicely coded and i dont think there is better way of doing what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: +1 beat me to it. i would recommend naming the `mousemove` event to something like `mousemove.myAction` to avoid conflict with any other listeners that might be attached; especially because this is a dynamically attached/removed event listener.

Comment: Binding the `mouseup` event like this can be problematic if the the mouse is outside the *dragged* element while releasing the mouse button. It's better to unbind on `document.mouseup` or similar.

Comment: I edited your code to include `, mousemove` on the `.off()` so that only that function will be unbinded from the mousemove event. Doing a straight `.off(mousemove)` will unbind every function from that event which can cause awful problems when working with multiple developers

Comment: I agree with some comments. Updated accordingly

Comment: mouseleave would be a good alternative to binding mouseup on the document, but both perform the same i suppose.